# JSP ERROR TOKEN

Tags: java, jsp

This is my Jsp:

```
<%if(null != request.getAttribute(ControllerBase.MSG_NOUSER)){%>
<%ControllerBase.MSG_NOUSER.toString()%>    
<%}%>
```

MSG_NOUSER is a public string constant.
I have "Syntax error on token ")", delete this token" on the second closing tag:      <%ControllerBase.MSG_NOUSER.toString()%>.
Why?

Comment: why do you close the jsp part each line? you can just open it in the first line and close it after the last line

Comment: Java statements end with a semi-colon. It would probably be more obvious if you put Java code in Java source files, and stopped using Java code in JSPs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP Scriptlets are typical Java code, you need to follow Java coding convetions and syntax, so you need to change as below **(; is missing for the line inside the if block)**:

```
<% if(null != request.getAttribute(ControllerBase.MSG_NOUSER)){ %>
<% ControllerBase.MSG_NOUSER.toString(); %>    
<% } %>
```